# How to get Equation of a decision boundary in matlab svm plot?

Tags: svm, matlab-figure

[image]
my data
y   n   Rh  y2
1   1   1.166666667 1
-1  2   0.5 1
-1  3   0.333333333 1
-1  4   0.166666667 1
1   5   1.666666667 2
1   6   1.333333333 1
-1  7   0.333333333 1
-1  8   0.333333333 1
1   9   0.833333333 1
1   10  2.333333333 2
1   11  1   1
-1  12  0.166666667 1
1   13  0.666666667 1
1   14  0.833333333 1
1   15  0.833333333 1
-1  16  0.333333333 1
-1  17  0.166666667 1
1   18  2   2
1   19  0.833333333 1
1   20  1.333333333 1
1   21  1.333333333 1
-1  22  0.166666667 1
-1  23  0.166666667 1
-1  24  0.333333333 1
-1  25  0.166666667 1
-1  26  0.166666667 1
-1  27  0.333333333 1
-1  28  0.166666667 1
-1  29  0.166666667 1
-1  30  0.5 1
1   31  0.833333333 1
-1  32  0.166666667 1
-1  33  0.333333333 1
-1  34  0.166666667 1
-1  35  0.166666667 1

my codes r

```
  data=xlsread('btpdata.xlsx',1.)
  A = data(1:end,2:3)
  B = data(1:end,1)
  svmStruct = svmtrain(A,B,'showplot',true)
  hold on
  C = data(1:end,2:3)
  D = data(1:end,4)
  svmStruct = svmtrain(C,D,'showplot',true)
  hold off
```

How can i get the approximate equations of this black lines in the given mat-lab plot?

Comment: How was this figure generated?  Please share the code on how this plot came to be.  Showing us that code is a good start and it may be one step closer from not getting voted to close.

Comment: Aproximatedly `y=0.6`

Answer (score 1):

It depends what package you did use, but as it is a linear Support Vector Machine there are more or less two options:

- Your trained svm contains the equation of the line in a property `coefs` (sometimes called `w` or `weights`) and `b` (or `intercept`), so your line is `<coefs, X> + b = 0`
- Your svm containes `alphas` (dual coefficients, Lagrange multipliers) and then `coefs = SUM_i alphas_i * y_i * SV_i` where `SV_i` is i'th support vector (the ones in circles on your plot) and `y_i` is its label (-1 or +1). Sometimes `alphas` are already multiplied by `y_i`, then your `coefs = SUM_i alphas_i * SV_i`.

If you are trying to get the equation from the actual plot (image), then you can only read it (and it is more or less `y = 0.6`, meaning that `coefs = [0 1]` and `b = -0.6`. Image analysis based approach (for arbitrary such plot) would require:

- detecting image part (object detection)
- reading the ticks/scale (OCR + object detection) <- this would be actually the hardest part
- filtering out everything non-black and performing linear regression to points left, then trasforming through scale detected earlier.

Comment: can u tell me command to take out coefs form this trained svm ?

Comment: everything is placed in SVMStruct returned from yout train method, http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html

Comment: there is no property named coefs listed there also i have tried "svmStruct.coefs",and "svmStruct.Coefs" both its not working

Comment: you seem to not read the whole answer - the other option is to get it by hand from `alphas` and `support vectors` - both accesible in your model.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. To build the linear equation (y = mx + b) of the decision boundary you need the gradient (m) and the y-intercept (b). SVMStruct.Bias is the b-term. The gradient is determined by the SVM beta weights, which SVMStruct does not contain so you need to calculate them from the alphas (which are included in SVMStruct):

```
alphas = SVMStruct.Alpha;
SV = SVMStruct.SupportVectors;
betas = sum(alphas.*SV);
m = betas(1)/betas(2)
```

By the way, if your SVM has scaled the data, then I think you will need to unscale it.